# How do i clone my whole EE instance into a test instance?

Tags: ee2

I want clone another instance for testing purposes.

I am trying to follow this guide:
https://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/operations/moving.html

but I'm not sure where to locate the database in Step 4.

And I'm not sure how to verify and update the files in Steps 8 and 9.

Right now I just have a copy of admin.php, index.php, themes/, images/, and system/ in my test/ directory.
And so, accessing www.mywebsite.com/test/ results in unavailable webpage.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's about PHP and MySQL.

Comment: You'll need to be familiar with accessing, exporting, and importing MySQL databases in order to successfully install and move EE instances. It's beyond the scope of this site to go into the details of how to do those things - a quick Google search or Stack Overflow might be a better option for you here.

Comment: I found this question useful.

Answer (score 2):

It's just a matter of copying all the files to a new location, cloning the database and updating the database connection info in database.php

The database is a MySQL database so you will need to do an SQL dump from there. The database connection info is in /system/expressionengine/config/database.php and you will need to either use the command line, a MySQL GUI tool such as Sequel Pro, or something like PHPMyAdmin to export the entire database as an SQL file.

However, you'll probably find things infinitely simpler if you use a multiple config system such as [Focus Labs Config](https://github.com/focuslabllc/ee-master-config). This will allow you to easily set up different configurations for different domains. Generally this is used when you want a local dev environment, staging environment, and a production server.

If you don't want to do that you could look at Deeploy Helper (assuming it's still available) which will let you change paths across your installation from a single place. It's useful but nowhere near as useful as using a multiple config system.